# Personalization of superset deck.gl geojson javavscript data interceptor

Tags: javascript, polygon, geojson, apache-superset, deck.gl

I try to reproduce the example provided by superset on deck.gl path in the deck.gl geojson graph but without success. The example works fine after modifying config.py but the colors are not displayed in deck.gl geojon. Furthermore, I cannot find any documentation on the use of javascript on map type graphics. I have the same problem for deck.gl polygon

[deck.gl geojson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCSpT.png)[deck.gl polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaL7Y.png)